# How to run same instance of container view in multiple view controller

Tags: ios, swift, instance, uicontainerview

This is my setup:

[image: my storyboard]

I want to present a small media player on top of a tab bar. 
I created a container view which is embedded in three different view controllers. That works but there is one catch. 
There seem to be 3 instances of that container view (Main Bottom Player View Controller) so that if the user presses e.g. the heart button the button changes but not in the other view controllers where the container view is embedded in.

Is there a better solution?

Thank you

PS: I use Swift 4 in Xcode 9

Comment: Your view is just that - a view. The data that it displays should come from some data model that is shared by the views. When a view appears it should reflect the current state of that data model

Comment: How can I set this up so that the state of e.g the heart button changes everytime it changes state in all view controllers and not just when viewDidLoad is being called?

Comment: When your button state changes, where are you storing the new state? is there a data model?

Comment: Typically you would refresh the view sate from your data model in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: Or you could send a Notification to indicate that the user has requested to favourite that item (or whatever action the heart is meant to represent).

Comment: Here is how my music player class works: In the music player class I declared 2 variables, one for the state of the music playing (determined by the play/ pause button image change) and the other one for the state of having the currently playing song liked (determined by the state of the heart button). If the user clicks on the buttons, the image of it changed and the corresponding var changes the Bool, too. No datamodels of any kind. Tbh I‘ve never used them. But I think the time has come! Could anyone please explain me step-by-step what to do? Thank you I would really appreciate that!